# Syntax error that only happens at the clients end

Tags: php

I'm having some difficulty finding what I'm doing wrong.

I was writing a Wordpress theme for a client that works fine on my end, but when the client tries it out they get an parsing error that I can't seem to fix since I'm not even sure what the issue is.

The line of code where the error occurs is:

```
<div class="custom-image"  style="background-image:url( <?php echo get_option('hi_theme_options')['image_upload']; ?> );"></div>
```

The error they get says this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';'
```

I have tried to get my server to give me more strict error parsing but I can't get this error on my end and for that reason I'm having problems debugging and fixing the error.

Comment: What's the *actual* source that the client sees? Not the PHP, but the site source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This should be happening for everyone as PHP is server-based and is not affected by the client. Make sure you are reproducing the error using the exact steps your client's end.)

Looks like you are doing [array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php). This is only available in PHP 5.4+. Check your version of PHP to verify you are running that version.

Comment: Yes, I'm using 5.5.3. That makes sense, I should have asked them what version they are using, amateur hour here :)

Answer (score 0):

Like it has been pointed out here the client is using a different version of PHP than I am. So the correct way would be to create a variable that holds the functions return values and select the array value from it.

```
<?php
$hioptions = get_option('hi_theme_options');

print($hioption['image_upload']);
?>
```